# Physics problems for submission

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I often enjoyed solving and submitting problems in the American Mathematical Monthly and other Journals which have such problems. There is a lot of this type of thing for mathematics. But I wondered whether there are also Journals in Physics which have problems and solutions section, where one can submit things and have them published? I do not mean problems on the level of high school students or targeted for students, but more a rough equivalent of the Monthly, just for physics instead of mathematics. 
Can someone tell me if this exists?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't believe it's about physics within the scope of the site. This could be one to be discussed by the community on [meta].